# Phase difference circuit - Bias problem

Tags: simulation, ltspice, bias, ultrasound, phase-shift

I'm working on a circuit which measures the phase difference between to signals that work in ultrasound range (~20 kHz).

With help I could achieve the circuit that I expected:
[image]

But now I need to use only positive DC.

The changes I made in the circuit allow me to detect positive phase difference (when I change the bottom generator) but it gives only ~0v when I put a negative value in the generator.

I want to bias the output so the circuit works as the old one but mounted to a DC. The range will be divided by two but it doesn't matter.

Here are the links to both circuits in LTSpice
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/be6k6jhx6h9ipo5/AACywKL40KTgJz2wyFPXie0sa?dl=1

Comment: Firstly, you are powering the LT1720 with 10 V which is above the Absolute maximum of 7 V. Secondly, pulling TTL signals below ground (your -ve Vin) does nothing. If you need to be able to compare both +ve and -ve input voltage then you need to design you interface to do that conversion.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your response. If you check the new circuit, the comparators are only powered with 5v.
On the other hand, I didn't understand what are you meaning with the second point

Comment: Assuming an input signal symmetrically +/- around zero. You are only able to detect the -ve to +ve transition of the input signal. Effectively you half wave rectify the input signal.  Can you draw some waveforms of what you expect to detect?

Comment: The signals that I want to detect are almost sines. It's the same signal but one input is the current and the other is the voltage. I need to measure when the phase difference is almost zero.

Comment: Ah...closer to the problem. Do you want to know just whether the current signal leads or lags the voltage or do you need to know when the difference between the two (whether lead or lag) is within a very small window? If so what is the window size... uS, nS?  In other words do you want to know the phase angle or do you want to know when they are exactly (close as can be) to in phase.

Comment: I need to measure the signals to make a plot in the computer of the phase difference. I need to see if the current leads or lag the voltage, so I need to know the phase angle. 
The next step is to define the window, but first I need to plot the phase angle

Comment: If you are processing in a computer, then it would seem sensible to digitize the phase difference as early as possible in your capture chain. Capturing a flag for Lead/Lag you already have done, but I'm not sure the phase angle (through a low pass filter) is going to be accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you consider trying to capture the phase difference digitally rather than in analog form and then digitize.
I had some difficulties with LTspice in terms of keeping amplitudes of input signals in line, so I took out the DC offsets in the circuit below. This produces a count of phase shift (Lead or Lag) based on a 10 MHz clock.
I'm not suggesting you'd do it this way, but it serves as a sample.
I'd suggest that the digital section would be a small MCU (you could test on an Arduino type hardware platform for example) with the XOR being the enable for a Timer-counter.

[image]

I broke several rules in the circuit above, such as no DC offset and no clip on the input, but it produces the right sort of output.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response! I just finished doing the circuit and I don't understand how to process the output given by the circuit with an Arduino to get the phase angle. I just have to count the number of clock pulses? Sorry but I never work with digital features of Arduino

Comment: I'm not actually suggesting you use the circuit proposed AND an Arduino to provide the solution. For example I'd not want to create V3, but use the MCU clock (or some derivative) to provide the measurement clock. You could start with an Arduino by simply incrementing a register in a tight loop base don the width of the XOR gate output.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the delay. I like your proposal,  that's why I keep asking you :) I'm currently working with an Arduino Due to digitalize the values from the phase shift, so it would be very useful your aproximation. I don't understand very well what are the problems. Can you help me to achieve the expected circuit?

Comment: Hi, I worked around your circuit to achieve the circuit that I expected. Now I'm trying to improve some features of the circuit. If you are interested, I can share it with you so we can see it

Comment: Sure, I'd love to see how you have progressed. If my answer added value you should accept it too.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/be6k6jhx6h9ipo5/AACywKL40KTgJz2wyFPXie0sa?dl=1
Thank you :)
I'm looking to do what is shown in the schematic. I know it seems that some steps are not necessary but I need to keep the the circuit as it is because I'm going to do another things with the Lag and Lead output, for example. The problem is that the frequency shifts along time, and I need to adjust the time when I send the pulse to reset the counter. I have the frequency because I do a FFT of the signal with the Arduino, I want to send that value in some way to adjust the time of this pulse. Any idea?

Comment: I accomplish what I expect from your circuit, so I must thank you again. In a few days I will start doing it. So I want to ask you what were you meaning when you said _I broke several rules in the circuit above, such as no DC offset and no clip on the input, but it produces the right sort of output_ I don't understand the _clip_ part. I'm sorry to keep asking questions but my deadline for this project is coming and I'm a little bit nervous.

Comment: The problems are small. I ignored your original request for a DC offset on the signals. Since the signals are symmetrical around zero, the front end is effectively acting as zero crossing detectors. If this is working for you, then that's ok. The last thing 'clip' ....if you put a 10k series resistor in each input line, then clipping will work (there are internal diodes in the LT1720)  ...this will clip the negative portion of the signal. That should be all.  Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use an op amp to generate a pseudo-ground at 2.5 volts.

2) AC-couple your inputs, and reference the inputs to the pseudo-ground.

3) Reference output filter to pseudo-ground,

4) Add another comparator (not an LT1720) to level shift the XOR gate output to pseudo-ground. Alternatively, if you're not that interested in accuracy, level shift by providing a voltage divider from the XOR to +5, with equal value resistors. A fine trim pot at the middle of the divider is probably a good idea.

5) Replace Q1 with an analog gate such a CD4066.

6) Reference your output meter to pseudo-ground, not ground.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I have two questions: 1) Which comparator would suit best (from point 4), a fast one or not? 
2) Is there any other option than CD4066. I'm couldn't find a third party model :(

Comment: @AugustoBonelliToro - 1) Unless you are doing super-precise phase measurement, consider the phase error of 1 usec at 20 kHz. Your phase resolution and operating frequency determine the required speed. 2) There are any number of analog switches, but I picked the CD4066 because it is widely available and dirt cheap.

Comment: @AugustoBonelliToro - On second thought, a 4066 is not a good choice - with a 5 volt supply its on-resistance can be as high as 500 ohms. Google on "analog switch". Likewise, there should be no need for a 3rd comparator - drive the switch from the flip-flop directly.

Comment: Ok, I'll try with FF directly. Sorry to still asking questions, but I don't understand why I need to use another comparator.
From my maths, ideally I need 0.1us phase error, because it's 1º for 20 kHz

Comment: @AugustoBonelliToro - Umm, what part of  "there should be no need for a 3rd comparator" don' t you understand?

Comment: My bad! I do the circuit again and I tell you how it goes!
Thanks

Comment: @AugustoBonelliToro - Also, be aware that measuring phase differences near zero is notably difficult. You get problems due to rise and fall times, not to mention metastability issues on the flip-flop. Just a warning.